# Passing array element to a function in c

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, pass-by-reference

code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void display (int *);
void show(int **);
int main()
{
    int a[3] = {1,2,3} ; 
    display(&a[2]);
    return 0 ;
}
void display(int *n)
{
    show( &n );
}
void show (int *m)
{
    printf("%d",**m);
}
```

My aim is to define a function name "show" which can be called from a function name "display" and both the functions ("show" and "display") must be called by reference .The above program gives an error on the "printf line" of the "show()" that "invalid type argument of unary '*' ". Is there any error in this program ?

Comment: You will increase your chances of getting an answer if you indent your code.

Comment: `void show (int *m)` --> `void show (int **m)`

Comment: Its the parameters which can be called by reference and not the function.

Answer (score 0):

Function declarator of `show` in definition doesn't match with its prototype.Change

```
void show (int *m)
{
    printf("%d",**m);
}
```

to

```
void show (int **m)
{
    printf("%d",**m);
}
```